# Problema de enrutado en areas usando MVC .Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, controller

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que tiene una capa de presentación con varias Áreas, y se me está dificultando el hace pruebas la aplicación, ya que los controladores y vistas que estoy desarrollando, se encuentran en un área definida.

Estuve buscando información acerca de trabajar con áreas, y a pesar que en cuanto a la definición del área está todo claro, no logro establecer que al iniciar la aplicación, el controlador y vista por defecto, sean los que yo le indico en la configuración.

En el archivo `RouteConfig.cs` tego esto:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace XXX.Inv.Odin.Web
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "Default",
            //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { controller = "NegocioCompra", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //);

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                //defaults: new { controller = "NegocioCompra", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                defaults: new { controller = "BusquedaInicial", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Y en el área donde estoy trabajando, (bien Raiz) tengo lo siguiente:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace XXX.Inv.Odin.Web.Areas.BienRaiz
{
    public class BienRaizAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "BienRaiz";
            }
        }
        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "BienRaiz_default",
                "BienRaiz/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Acá hay una foto de cómo está esquematizado el proyecto en el explorador de proyectos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien tiene una idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu `AreaRegistration` debe estar estructurada de esta manera

```
public class ForumAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get { return "BienRaiz";  }
    }
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "BienRaiz_default",
            "BienRaiz/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "BienRaiz.Controllers" }//referencia a los controladores de esta área
        );
    }
}
```

y en tu **RouteConfig**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //defaults: new { controller = "NegocioCompra", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        defaults: new { controller = "BusquedaInicial", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "XXX.Inv.Odin.Web.Controllers" }//haciendo referencia a los controladores del proyecto main
    );
}
```

Prácticamente lo único que te hizo falta es la referencia a los controladores de cada aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Especifica bien por favor la referencia

```
namespaces: new string[] { "XXX.Inv.Odin.Web.Controllers" }
```

que hay que poner en cada punto